# как возвратить ответ на запрос http в формате json

Tags: golang, http

При http запросе с какого либо клиента по адресу http://localhost:8080 сервер должен возвратать ответ в формате json. Только изучаю golang. Подскажите. Спасибо. Вот мой код. 
**main.go**

```
package main

import (
 "encoding/json"
 "net/http"
)

func main() {
 http.HandleFunc("/", myController1)
 http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil)
}

type Number struct {
 Id int64 `json:"id"` // свойство Id будет преобразовано в ключ "id"
 Num int64 `json:"num"` // свойство Num будет преобразовано в ключ "num"
 En string `json:"en"` // свойство En будет преобразовано в ключ "en"
 Ru string `json:"ru"` // свойство Ru будет преобразовано в ключ "ru"
}

func myController1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

 n0 := Number {
  Id: 0,
  Num: 0,
  En: "zero",
  Ru: "ноль",
 }

 decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
 err := decoder.Decode(&n0)
 if err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }

 //проверка
 //w.Write([]byte("<h1>Hello World!</h1>"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот это:

```golang
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
err := decoder.Decode(&n0)
```

Должно быть:

```golang
encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
err := encoder.Encode(&n0)
```

Вам же кодировать ответ, а не декодировать запрос.

Comment: Уважаемый Ainar-G! Огромное ВАМ спасибо!